# Include Issue Calling an External PHP Script from Expression Engine

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to call an external PHP script from an Expression Engine form response template that sends emails using Mandrill API.  The script I have works on regular PHP, I have tested it, but there is some sort of issue with the path for the includes.  I've double checked the absolute paths and they are correct.  Anyone see an issue?

```
require_once '/www/host/public_html/mandrill-api-php/Mandrill.php';
require_once '/www/host/public_html/mandrill-api-php/madrillSend.php';

$msg = "TEST MESSAGE";

$location = "{location}";
$ebrochure = "{ebrochure}"; 

$output = SendMandrill($location, $msg, $ebrochure);

echo $output;
```

=================================================

```
function SendMandrill($location, $msg, $ebrochure) {

    $mandrill = new Mandrill('xxx');
    $message = array(
        'html' => null,
        'text' => $msg,
        'subject' => $subj,
        'from_email' => 'leads@yourdomain.com',
        'from_name' => 'Leads Account',
        'to' => array('email' => 'jon@otherdomain.com', 'type' => 'to),
        'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'leads@yourdomain.com'),
        'important' => false,
    );

    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
    $send_at = '';
    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
    return $result;

}
```

==================================================

Warning: require_once(/www/host/public_html/mandrill-api-php/madrillSend.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/host/public_html/system/core/core.functions.php(634) : eval()'d code on line 15

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/www/host/public_html/mandrill-api-php/madrillSend.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/phpz     ) in /www/host/public_html/system/core/core.functions.php(634) : eval()'d code on line 15

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? There are all these variations (assuming /www/host/public_html/ is where your EE install is and is your document root):

```
require_once('/www/host/public_html/mandrill-api-php/Mandrill.php');

require_once('../../../../../mandrill-api-php/Mandrill.php';

require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . 'mandrill-api-php/Mandrill.php');

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'mandrill-api-php/Mandrill.php');
```

and like 10 others. It's always possible the error is reporting the path you put in, but it actuality it's trying to load it from a relative path because EE or CI set's an environment thing. Just guessing a little, but try out some varaitions and report back.

Are file permissions all correct? Do you have two different PHP agents (one for EE core, one running everything else)?

**edit** Are these templates set on PHP Input or Output?? If set on Input, your $location and $ebrochure variables won't get set properly.

Comment: I utilized the third item and now I'm not getting an error message, but the email isn't sending.  The page renders normally but doesn't show the output variable...will print_r work in a template?

Comment: Yup. Go with var_dump though, it's usually more informative.

Comment: Now I get this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /www/host/public_html/system/core/core.functions.php(634) : eval()'d code on line 14

Comment: Permissions 755, PHP output...

Comment: Could be curl or not PHP 5.2.  Running 5.1.6, requirements say 5.2

Comment: Oh is this EE 1? Sorry man, I just don't have any copies of it and probably can't track this down for you. Hopefully someone can help. You should always mention that you're running EE 1.x in your questions.

Comment: jesus, PHP 5.1.6? whatever you do, don't post your actual domain anywhere, there have been a ton of security vuln since then. **edit** yea dude, it's in your answer, wipe that out before someone makes you pay for it.

Comment: Yes, I changed that.  Any ideas on the eval()'d code error?

Comment: Ok, now Mandrill doesn't work because it uses json_encode, which PHP 5.2

Comment: I highly recommend you upgrade both your environment and ExpressionEngine. I would plead with a client running those versions to let me do the upgrade, or not take the contract. Good luck.

Comment: http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/ might help you around your problem.